# How to pass file contents to serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm a new at django.
I need to implement two POST options; one from url parameters and the other from file data.

eg, `curl -X POST localhost:8000/api/test?key=value` 
OR `curl -X POST -F "file=@myfile.json" localhost:8000/api/test`

I tested with below but failed.

```
class TestEntryView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = TestEntry.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
    serializer_class = TestEntrySerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if self.request.FILES.get('file'):
            file_obj = request.FILES['file']
            filename = '/api/mytest/.temp/testfile'
            with open(filename, 'wb+') as temp_file:
                for chunk in file_obj.chunks():
                    temp_file.write(chunk)
            with open(filename, 'r') as temp_file:
                data = json.load(temp_file)
                serializer.save(**data)
        serializer.save()
```

=> `perform_create()` is not getting called due to validating field failed.  Is there recommended way for this purpose?

Comment: "due to validating field failed": so what fields fail validation and why don't you change validation in your serializer?

Comment: Note also that `file_obj` is an `UploadedFile` so you don't necessarily need to first save it to read it. It supports `open()` and `read()`. You're loading it entirely into memory anyway when you call `json.loads()` so using `chunks()` isn't very useful.

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten. The serializer have related field and this could be the reason. After modifying the related field it works :)